# EF Linq query is incrementing parameter @p__linq__n

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

Entity Framework 4 is generating a SQL statement from a fairly innocuous linq query that includes the standard parameter variables, however the numeric parameter suffix is incrementing continually for each successive run of the query. The calling code is not being run in any asynchronous or transactional manner.

This only seems to happening in our production environment and I cannot replicate it in the development environment, wherein each run of the code that calls this query generates parameters @p__linq__0 and @p__linq__1

**Sample linq:**

```
var myJob =
  (from job in this.context.Jobs
   where job.Contract.ContractNo == contractNo && job.JobNo == jobNo
   select job).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Sample sql queries being generated:**

```
SELECT ... WHERE ([Extent2].[ContractNo] = @p__linq__1799) AND ([Extent1].[JobNo] = @p__linq__1800)  )  AS [Limit1]
SELECT ... WHERE ([Extent2].[ContractNo] = @p__linq__8262) AND ([Extent1].[JobNo] = @p__linq__8263)  )  AS [Limit1]
SELECT ... WHERE ([Extent2].[ContractNo] = @p__linq__3590) AND ([Extent1].[JobNo] = @p__linq__3591)  )  AS [Limit1]
SELECT ... WHERE ([Extent2].[ContractNo] = @p__linq__788) AND ([Extent1].[JobNo] = @p__linq__789)  )  AS [Limit1]
SELECT ... WHERE ([Extent2].[ContractNo] = @p__linq__2250) AND ([Extent1].[JobNo] = @p__linq__2251)  )  AS [Limit1]
```

I can't work out why these numbers are increasing, and the problem with the parameter names changing like this is that it's causing SQL Server to generate a new execution plan for each query.

Comment: the parameter post fix increases for each parameter starts when db context is initialized, perhaps you keep the db context alive for a long time then use the same query multiple time..